# IntelliJ IDEA 14 gradle loading dependencies with classifier OR without classifier; not AND

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I have a gradle testCompile dependency with classifier:

```
testCompile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-kernel', version: "${neo4jVersion}", classifier: 'tests'
```

My project also requires the neo4j-kernel as-is (no classifier) via spring data neo4j. However when I include the above line in my build.gradle I only get this dependency and not anymore the neo4j-kernel dependency, which results in my project not being able to build anymore. In IntelliJ 13 I did not have this problem. Does anybody know how to solve this?

I have tried adding:

```
compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-kernel', version: "${neo4jVersion}"
```

but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is know issue, IntelliJ version 14.0.1 will contain the fix for this.

Ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127178